# Find Out the URL of the webpage that image resides on

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httpresponse, httphandler

I would like to make a 1 pixel image that will reside on the html page to track page activity
I have a page `http:/domain.com/mypage.htm`
and I want to add `<img src='http://www.test.com/myimage.aspx' />`  somewhere in its body

When page is triggered I render an one pixel transparent image.  I'm having an issue finding out the URL of the page that image is on.  HTTP_REFERER header carrier the true referer of the page, and HTTP_HOST carries the URL of the image itself.

Is there a way to find out the HTML page URL that the image is on?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with an image. When the image is fetched, another GET request is sent to the server, and there are no ties between the Page GET and the Image GET. To do this, the best approach would be to use JavaScript, and send an asynchronous request to a handler with the data you require. (Similar to how Google Analytics works)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it on any http header, you can always send some information like `<img src='http://www.test.com/myimage.aspx?page=mypage' />`.

If you can use javascript though, you don't need to display an image, use an ajax request instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can analysis the request headers of `myimage.aspx`, the `Referer` header is the HTML page URL you're looking for. Besides, I suggest adding a timestamp with the `<img>` src link, like this:

```
<img src="http://www.test.com/myimage.aspx?t=1234567890" />
```

So that every time you refresh the HTML page, the browser invoke a new request to the image.